# Strange behaviour while inserting into spliced lists?

Tags: python, python-2.7

What I am trying to achieve is to insert a small 2D-list into a big one (I'm using Python 2.7.3).

Why am I getting different results for `var1` and `var2`?

```
def modify(foo):
    small = [[1]*2]*2
    for y, line in enumerate(small):
        foo[y+1][1:3] = line
    return foo

var1 = [[0]*4]*4
var2 = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0]]

print modify(var1)
print modify(var2)

# Result:
# var1 = [
#   [0, 1, 1, 0],
#   [0, 1, 1, 0],
#   [0, 1, 1, 0],
#   [0, 1, 1, 0]]
#
# var2 = [
#   [0, 0, 0, 0],
#   [0, 1, 1, 0],
#   [0, 1, 1, 0],
#   [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using `[[0]*4]*4` you are in fact creating a single list (`[0]*4`) and referencing it four times.

```
>>> var1 = [[0]*4]*4
>>> var1
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> var1[0][0] = 2
>>> var1
[[2, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> var1[0] is var1[1]
True
```

It's a little clearer if you replace the inner content with a variable

```
>> inner = [0]*4
>> var1 = [inner, inner, inner, inner]
>>> var1
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> inner[0] = 1
>>> var1
[[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Everyone comes across this at least once while working with Python. One of those times where Python's hidden use of pointers comes back to bite you.

Answer (score 2):

`[0]*4` creates `[0, 0, 0, 0]`, however, `[[0,0,0,0]]*4` creates a list containing shallow copies of `[0,0,0,0]`. That means, all inner lists are the same.